# protractor - map element attribute to element text

Tags: javascript, protractor

My HTML code looks like this

```html
<div class='ag-row' row-id='3245'>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col1'>Value1</div>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col2'>Value2</div>
<div class='ag-row' row-id='3249'>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col1'>Value12</div>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col2'>Value13</div>
<div class='ag-row' row-id='3216'>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col1'>Value14</div>
  <div clsss='ag-cell' col-id='col2'>Value15</div>
```

I am trying to use protractor map function to return the rows assigned to their respective row-id(unique id generated in html for every row). I have 2 code snippets here. Snippet 1 works fine, but I am trying to achieve snippet 2.

In snippet 2, rowId is not being recognized as a key. Am I using it right? if not, is there a better way to solve this issue?

Snippet 1:

```html
const rows = element.all(by.css(".ag-row"));

rows.map((row) => {
  return {
    id : row.getAttribute("row-id");
    row : row.getText();
  }
});
```

```html
const rows = element.all(by.css(".ag-row"));

rows.map((row) => {

  return row.getAttribute("row-id").then((rowId) => {
    return {
      rowId: row.getText()
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just built my own map

```html
const rows = element.all(by.css(".ag-row"));

    return rows.then((rows) => {
      const rowMap = new Map();
      for (const row of rows) {
        row.getAttribute("row-id").then((rowId) => {
          row.getText().then((rowText) => {
            rowMap.set(rowId, rowText);
          });
        });
      }
      return rowMap;
    });
```